# Change of limits of integration: $ \int_2^x \frac{\pi(x/u)}{\log u}du$

Tags: integration

This is a change of variables that I do not see. $\pi(v)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $v.$

$$I_1 = \int_2^x \frac{\pi(x/u)}{\log u}du$$

becomes via $v = x/u$

$$I_2 = x\int_2^{x/2}\frac{\pi(v)}{\log x- \log v}\frac{dv}{v^2}  $$

I see that if we let $v = x/u$ we have $du = -x/v^2$ so

$$- x\int_2^? \frac{\pi(v)}{\log(x/v)} \frac{dv}{v^2}  $$

I understand the expansion of $\log(x/v)$ but I don't see where the (-) sign went nor do I understand how the new upper limit is found.

This occurs on p. 206 of Landau's *Handbuch* with very faded type. Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower limit on $I_2$ should be $1$, not 2: when $u=2$, $v=x/2$ and when $u=x$, $v=1$.  Thus

$$
\int_2^x\frac{\pi(x/u)}{\log(u)}du=-x\int_{x/2}^1\frac{\pi(v)}{\log(x/v)}\frac{dv}{v^2}=x\int_1^{x/2}\frac{\pi(v)}{\log(x/v)}\frac{dv}{v^2}
$$  The negative sign goes away when we flip the order of integration (integrating from 1 to $x/2$ instead of from $x/2$ to 1).